# Salesforce Bulk API upload via postman

Tags: salesforce-lightning

I am trying to use postman for update huge number of records.
I am using Bulk api with operations 'update'
1. created update job
2. updating data using csv format.
Both the commands are successful. But the job is not showing any record. also not updating the records.
Can you guys give me a sample postman for bulk api update for existing records in the system